# How to calculate breaks and stops in Chained through time pattern

Tags: timefold

I saw in the TimeFold documentation the design pattern to do continuous planning. I have seen an example of a schedule and would like to know how sleeping time or extra working time is taken into account in the resolution. [timefold example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzQiG.png)

There is an example of code that implements this pattern ?
Are the breaks calculated at the time of the update of the time to arrive in the listener of the shadow variable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's done in the VariableListener of the arrival time and/or departure time calculcation.

Basically:

- If the service duration passes 17:00, it continues from 9:00 the next day (sometimes adding the travel time from vehicle home again).
- If the travel duration passes 17:00, they drive home instead and start the next day from home to the new visit.